# Carthage: Missing extension: public.vcs.subversion

Tags: ios, xcode, carthage

I have problem when I want to update my frameworks using carthage update. This is what I get:

```
*** Cloning Dollar.swift
*** Checking out Dollar.swift at "3.0.2"
*** xcodebuild output can be found in /var/folders/5d/3trcth_x5zj6f_pmk2k0hl080000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.qtRFgh.log
*** Building scheme "Cent" in Dollar.xcworkspace
2015-06-17 10:47:38.176 xcodebuild[5064:240253] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-7718/IDEFoundation/SourceControl/Model/IDESourceControlManager.m:423
Details:  Error Domain=com.apple.dt.IDESourceControlErrorDomain Code=-1 "Missing extension: public.vcs.subversion" UserInfo=0x7fd36e2e3e90 {NSLocalizedDescription=Missing extension: public.vcs.subversion}
Object:   
Method:   -loadRepositories
Thread:   {number = 1, name = main}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
2015-06-17 10:47:51.127 xcodebuild[5188:240631] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-7718/IDEFoundation/SourceControl/Model/IDESourceControlManager.m:423
Details:  Error Domain=com.apple.dt.IDESourceControlErrorDomain Code=-1 "Missing extension: public.vcs.subversion" UserInfo=0x7fda46396010 {NSLocalizedDescription=Missing extension: public.vcs.subversion}
Object:   
Method:   -loadRepositories
Thread:   {number = 1, name = main}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/bialek/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dollar-cnpzzqqzcseuvucrfghsizcweovz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/bialek/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dollar-cnpzzqqzcseuvucrfghsizcweovz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/bialek/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dollar-cnpzzqqzcseuvucrfghsizcweovz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/bialek/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dollar-cnpzzqqzcseuvucrfghsizcweovz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos'
warning: skipping copy phase strip, binary is code signed: /Users/bialek/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dollar-hiqnxgsortokykbrcedgvcolwwqw/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Dollar.framework/Dollar
warning: skipping copy phase strip, binary is code signed: /Users/bialek/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dollar-hiqnxgsortokykbrcedgvcolwwqw/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Cent.framework/Cent
```

Cent framework appears but it should be also Dollar framework I think.

The same warning I get with Alamofire.

I have Xcode 6.3.2 and Carthage 0.7.4.

Does anybody know what is wrong?